# Remove items from list 1 not in list 2

Tags: c#, lambda

I am learning to write [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx), and I need help on how to remove all elements from a list which are not in another list.

```
var list = new List<int> {1, 2, 2, 4, 5};
var list2 = new List<int> { 4, 5 };

// Remove all list items not in List2
// new List Should contain {4,5}    
// The lambda expression is the Predicate.
list.RemoveAll(item => item. /*solution expression here*/ );

// Display results.
foreach (int i in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can do this via RemoveAll using Contains:

```
list.RemoveAll( item => !list2.Contains(item));
```

Alternatively, if you just want the intersection, using [Enumerable.Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) would be more efficient:

```
list = list.Intersect(list2).ToList();
```

The difference is, in the latter case, you will not get duplicate entries.  For example, if `list2` contained 2, in the first case, you'd get `{2,2,4,5}`, in the second, you'd get `{2,4,5}`.

Comment: see my enhancement to this answer (below) if you are comparing objects rather than scalars

Answer (score 21):

**Solution for objects** (maybe easier than horaces solution):

If your list contains objects, rather than scalars, it is that simple, by removing by **one selected property** of the objects:

```
    var a = allActivePatientContracts.RemoveAll(x => !allPatients.Select(y => y.Id).Contains(x.PatientId));
```

Comment: Great and simple solution, I wanted to do the same as the OP, but wanted to use objects. This solved it!

Answer (score 11):

This question has been marked as answered, but there is a catch. If your list contains an object, rather than a scalar, you need to do a bit more work.

I tried this over and over with Remove() and RemoveAt() and all sorts of things and none of them worked correctly. I couldn't even get a Contains() to work correctly. Never matched anything. I was stumped until I got the suspicion that maybe it could not match up the item correctly.

When I realized this, I refactored the *item* class to implement IEquatable, and then it started working.

Here is my solution:

```
class GenericLookupE : IEquatable<GenericLookupE>
{
    public string   ID  { get; set; }

    public bool     Equals( GenericLookupE other )
    {
        if ( this.ID == other.ID )      return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

After I did this, the above RemoveAll() answer by Reed Copsey worked perfectly for me.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx

Answer (score 11):

```
list = list.Except(list2).ToList();
```