# jquery Remove items from list 1 not in list 2

Tags: jquery

I have a seemingly very simple problem, but my bandwidth is so limited by now, and have searched SO but found [a relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066119/remove-items-from-list-1-not-in-list-2?rq=1) only applied to C#, I meant no luck yet.

HTML:

```
<ul class="first">
  <li data-id="1">One</li>
  <li data-id="2">Two</li>
  <li data-id="3">Thre</li>
  <li data-id="4">Four</li>
  <li data-id="5">Five</li>
  <li data-id="6">Six</li>
</ul>
<ul class="second">
  <li data-id="1">One</li>
  <li data-id="2">Two</li>
  <li data-id="3">Thre</li>
  <li data-id="4">Four</li>
</ul>
```

I want to remove the last 2 items from the first (hence Five and Six), because they do not exist in the second. Order is not important actually. The sample to simplify my problem.
Basically no clear idea to achieve this, sorry, so whenever I tried with .length check, I remove all the first items.

Any hint is very much appreciated. Thanks

UPDATED: 
Sorry my bad.
"Order is not important actually": I meant the lists may be unordered like:

```
<ul class="second">
  <li data-id="3">Thre</li>
  <li data-id="1">One</li>      
  <li data-id="4">Four</li>
  <li data-id="2">Two</li>
</ul>
```

Also applies to the first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're assessing equivalence by the `data-id` attribute:

```
$('.first li').filter(
    function(){
        return !$('.second li[data-id="' + $(this).data('id') + '"]').length;
    }).remove();​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hFLYu/).

References:

- [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew I should have asked, but I kept searching

Comment: Why are you filtering all `<li />`s? Shouldn't it be `$('.first li')`?

Comment: @lnrbob: yeah, it *should*. Originally I was planning to filter both lists to double-check, and then, as I was writing the `filter()` function, I realised that was pointlessly repetitive. But I forgot to amend the selector... *edited*, and thanks for the catch! =)

Comment: @DavidThomas no worries! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('ul.first li:gt(3)').remove();
```

Or:

```
var $first = $('.first li'), $second = $('.second li');

$first.filter(function(){
    return !$second.filter('[data-id='+ this.dataset.id +']').length
}).remove();
```

Comment: Sorry, can not apply greater than for more complex ID, can I?

Comment: @swan Do you want to remove the elements based on `data-id` attributes?

Comment: Yes, but data ID is not always integer, I meant can be data-id="new-1". Not only integer. Sorry for unclear question. It was said above not so clearly stated: "The sample to simplify my problem".

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var set1 = $('.first').children(),
    set2 = $('.second').children();

set1.filter(function() {
    var testingId = $(this).data('id'),
        found = set2.filter(function() {
            return $(this).data('id') === testingId;
        });

    return found.length === 0;
}).remove();
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Ehewz/

Answer (score 1):

```
// start by building a list of elements in list two.
var list2 = {};
$('.second li').each(function(){
    // by data id.
    list2[$(this).attr('data-id')] = true;
    // by text
    // list2[$(this).text()] = true;
});
// Then remove any values from the first list where it's data-id isn't in our list.
$('.first li').each(function(){
    // Make replacement here to match text.
    if( ! list2[ $(this).attr('data-id') ] ){
    // if( ! list2[ $(this).text() ] ){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```