# Remove unique item from unordered list

Tags: jquery, duplicates

I have two unordered lists. I want to remove items from the first that are not present in the second list.

Like this:

```
<ul class="first">
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Six</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="second">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

...run script...should be this:

```
<ul class="first">
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
</ul>
```

My problem is exactly like the one posted here - [jquery Remove items from list 1 not in list 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072505/jquery-remove-items-from-list-1-not-in-list-2)

...however, I can't seem to get it working with my code (it does nothing).

Here's what I tried:

```
$('.first li a').filter(
    function(){
    return !$('.second li').length;
}).remove();
```

With other code, I've been able to remove duplicates. However, I'm having issues doing the reverse. I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple, and I would appreciate a second set of eyes pointing out to me what the problem is.

Comment: How is this any different than [jquery Remove items from list 1 not in list 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072505/jquery-remove-items-from-list-1-not-in-list-2)?

Comment: `$('.second li').length` is 4.  It will *always* be 4.  So `!$('.second li').length` will *always* be `false`.  You need to actually compare elements.  Something like `$('.second li:contains("One")').length`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.first li').filter(function(){
    return ! $('.second li:contains('+$(this).text()+')').length;
}).remove();
```

Comment: Yeah, waiting for a filter

Comment: Shouldn't this really be `$('.first li').filter` or `$('.first li a').filter().parent().remove()`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat - yep, to remove the LI it should, and text() would work anyway!

Comment: Ah. I see what I was doing wrong now. This works perfectly! In one of my earlier attempts I was comparing .html(), but that it wasn't working (I suspect I had the syntax incorrect). Thanks!